# How to print the value of the object?

Tags: python, pitch-tracking

How to print the values of the objects?

```
    import amfm_decompy.pYAAPT as pYAAPT
    import amfm_decompy.basic_tools as basic

    signal = basic.SignalObj('microphone-results-6.wav')
    pitch = pYAAPT.yaapt(signal)
    print(pitch)
```

It is instead printing the object's address. Please help me

Comment: can you complete the question, I'm not able to see the content after as.

Comment: you can reach pitch object attribute -> PitchObj.attribute. list of all atributtes you have here http://bjbschmitt.github.io/AMFM_decompy/pYAAPT.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
pitch.samp_values
```

then you can plot it like that:

```
plt.plot(pitch.samp_values)
plt.show()
```