# How to print the value of "object at somthing"

Tags: python, azure

I am using Azure Confidential Ledger, and I am trying to query it. But when I want to print a variable that contain value I encounter following line as an output:

> bound method ConfidentialLedgerClientOperationsMixin.list_ledger_entries of <azure.confidentialledger._patch.ConfidentialLedgerClient object at 0x000001BAD31ED048>>

My code is as follow:

```
from azure.confidentialledger import ConfidentialLedgerClient
from azure.confidentialledger.certificate import ConfidentialLedgerCertificateClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

identity_client = ConfidentialLedgerCertificateClient()
network_identity = identity_client.get_ledger_identity(
    ledger_id="MyLedger"
)

ledger_tls_cert_file_name = "ledger_certificate.pem"
with open(ledger_tls_cert_file_name, "w") as cert_file:
    cert_file.write(network_identity["ledgerTlsCertificate"])

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ledger_client = ConfidentialLedgerClient(
    endpoint="https://MyLedger.confidential-ledger.azure.com",
    credential=credential,
    ledger_certificate_path=ledger_tls_cert_file_name
)

d = ledger_client.list_ledger_entries

print(d)
```

In addition, I have read following questions:

1. [How to print the value of the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900837/how-to-print-the-value-of-the-object)
2. [Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a)

Comment: Did you mean to **call** `list_ledger_entries`?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure...I wanted to query the ledger to see what is on it; thus, I thought maybe by printing "ledger_client.list_ledger_entries" I can achieve that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d = ledger_client.list_ledger_entries()
```

instead of this

```
d = ledger_client.list_ledger_entries
```

in your code, you did not assign the the result of the method call to the var d but instead assigned the method list_ledger_entries's object of ledger_client to d

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating...now there is a new issue, by using "d = ledger_client.list_ledger_entries()"...the output is: 
<iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x25cd3bb0b38>

Comment: ok that  great step into solving the prob!

Comment: now since its like that, that means the value doesnt have a __repr__ or __str__ magic method to it

Comment: try d = [ele for ele in edger_client.list_ledger_entries()]

Comment: Thanks, error:
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 128, in __next__
    return next(self._page_iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 76, in __next__
    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)